# Consulta que le permitá conocer el monto y la cantidad de una columna(transacciones) para mi tabla 'X' y 'y'

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, join

Poseo dos tablas, bansur y clap. Me planteo estas consultas: --ANTES DE RIDICULIZAR piensen en un momento de que un like a su respuesta vale mas que una simple colabaración---

-Escriba el código de SQL que le permite conocer el monto y la cantidad de las transacciones que SIMETRIK considera como conciliables para la base de CLAP

```
select FECHA_TRANSACCION.bansur, FECHA_TRANSACCION.clap,count(FECHA_TRANSACCION.clap)
from clap
FECHA_TRANSFERENCIA JOIN bansur FECHA_TRANSACCION 
on 
FECHA_TRANSACCION.ID_BANCO = FECHA_TRANSACCION.ID_ADQUIRIENTE;
```

~~ esto logre comprender ~~

2. Escriba el código de SQL que le permite conocer el monto y la cantidad de las transacciones que SIMETRIK considera como conciliables para la base de BANSUR.

```
select FECHA_TRANSACCION.bansur, FECHA_TRANSACCION.clap,count(FECHA_TRANSACCION.bansur)
from bansur
FECHA_TRANSACCION JOIN clap FECHA_TRANSACCION 
on 
 FECHA_TRANSACCION.ID_ADQUIRIENTE=FECHA_TRANSACCION.ID_BANCO;
```

~~ esto logre comprender ~~

NOta:Tengo una inquietud de resolver la segunda pregunta, debido a que no halló la forma de verle sentido puesto que realice la misma logica pero apuntando a la otra tabla clap.

IMPORTANTE: estoy leyendo un libro de SQL con ejercicios de aplicación y de ahí estoy comenzando (no es lo ideal pero soy creyente que los ejercicios de aplicación te refuerzan mas los conocimientos).

LOS ARCHIVOS DE .csv fueron importados por JupytherN, en PYthon por ende la etiqueta!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Ayer te dijeron que python no tenia que ver con tu pregunta.. y efectivamente, no tiene que ver con tu problema.. tu problema es SQL y vos queres que un experto en sql lo resuelva.. igual, no veo ningun problema a resolver aca.. tenes un query, que le pasa a ese query?? cual es el resultado esperado?? cual es el resultado obtenido??? que quiere decir conciliables??? Entende, que no estamos viendo nada de lo que vos ves.. y tenemos que adivinar, como esperas que te ayudemos...

Comment: Con python importe los .csv igual no le veo ruido que exista una etiqueta que diga PYthon, si este se uso como apoyo para favorecer algo de tu problematica. con respecto a la otro, si llegas a criticar es porque tu ego es tan grande que sos "experto en sql" y no pretendo que me lo resuelvan mas bien que me guien, debido a que ya tengo un poco comprendida la logica pero no me muestra lo pensado es no mas eso. conciliables es el cruce de las tablas.  que le pasa a ese query?? - no compila nada  cual es el resultado esperado?? - que me envie a mi tabla intermedia el resultado

Comment: Resolver es un verbo muy grande de tus dedos!! ahi tengo una consulta desarrollada de la posible solucion final...."un experto en sql " puede llegar y decirme che en la linea del select te falta esto o te sobra esto pero vas bien...Resolver todo es copiar mis 2 preguntas sin contexto y sin nada

Comment: no.. a ver.. python no tiene nada que ver, y como importaste tus datos no hacen tu pregunta. basicamente, si no decis que error tenes, alguien se tiene que poner a analizar todo el contexto para saber cual es tu problema, que es que el query esta mal escrito. En el from solo van los nombres de las tablas, y no los campos, ahi hay un campo de mas, que seguramente es lo que te dice el error, pero si no lo mostras es dificil adivinarlo. Si veniste a pedir consejo y te estamos pidiendo que aclares, mejor aclara... Aca todos los que te ayudan, lo hacen porque quieren. ayudanos a ayudarte...

Comment: Sigues con tu mala actitud y quejándote de los comentarios, pero no has respondido que hace que las transacciones sean conciliables con las bases clap y bansur. Se te pidió además un [mre].  Según lo que parece que has intentado con tus consultas, buscas que se concilien entre ambas tablas y los resultados serían iguales. Pero en ese caso, no tiene sentido que haya dos preguntas. El problema actual ni siquiera tiene que ver con SQL sino con entender la lógica de lo que se pregunta.

Comment: bueno gbianchi considero que por algo se empieza y lo que haces ya veo mas cooperacion. ents efectuare la recomendacion que me decis y te comento. Ahora bien cuando ajuste tus recomendaciones donde puedo anexar el resultado?

Comment: @gbianchi cuando compilo el query no me sale ningun error, estoy considerando a pensar que lo que decis es cierto en el from no van sentencias que no sean tablas, mi pregunta es como consolido el join ? - mas sin embargo hare tu sugerencia y indagare un poco mas. De verdad gracias

Comment: @CarlosHernandez Entender tu problema me llevo por lo menos 15 minutos, que si hubieras puesto el error, que sale mas que seguro, entonces no me hubiera pasado... y si, hay un error, y si, es ese, y si, cualquier herramienta que uses para ejecutar el query te va a decir que hay un error y por lo menos te va a decir donde esta....

Comment: Ahora, mas alla de eso, tu actitud de tengo un problema no me importa nada arreglenlo, no esta buena.. si la gente que TE QUIERE AYUDAR, te hace preguntas, las contestas a todas sin tanta altaneria...

Comment: @gbianchi como decirlo hasta la fecha la unica persona que se presento con buenas intenciones has sido vos! los demas solo llegan a ridiculizar. Son diferencias que deben ser asimiladas, porque si deseo colabarcion de mi parte siempre se escribe con respecto y asi mismo debo recibir respuestas con respeto, no ridiculizandome

Comment: con respecto al error no me imprime nada en la caja de salida, es como si quedara mal organizada la consulta

Comment: Entonces no la estas ejecutando.. o no estas mirando el log de salida.. pero siempre que ejecutas y hay un error, en algun lugar sale...

Comment: Y a mi tambien me maltrataste en los primeros mensajes cuando trate de ayudarte a organizar la pregunta... No voy a escribir tu query bien, quiero que entiendas tu problema y sepas resolverlo... ese query, esta mal, ese from esta mal...